# TFS 2010: Project file gets deleted on Get Latest Version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

We have a standard installation of TFS 2010 with a handful of developers.  We do have a number of projects with a number of branches but nothing to crazy.  Frequently we will go to get the latest version of a solution and TFS will delete the project file (csproj) of one of the projects, a MVC 3 web project.  Looking at the Source Control logs we see the following error:

```
One or more source control bindings for this solution are not valid and are listed below.
Source control bindings can be modified by selecting File, Source Control, Change Source Control from the main menu.
```

If we go into the pending changes view and undo the deleting of the project file everything works fine.  Does anyone know what the error message means and know what it is that we are doing that is causing it?

Environment:
TFS 2010
VS 2012
SQL Server 2008

Comment: Have you checked the source control binding status as the error message indicated?

Comment: They all look correct to me and they all have a Status of valid.

Comment: Happens to us as well (VS 2013.4). Usually, removing and recreating the workspace (not the files) is enough to get rid of the pending deletes. No idea why it happens in the first place though.